# hcard format for company address type

Tags: hcard

I'm looking for best way to use hCard format on my site and my concern is about type of company address

My contacts data goes like this:

> CompanyX
>   **Office** 28 Nulla St. Mankato Mississippi 96522
>
> ---
>
> CompanyX
>   **Headquarters** 92 Dictum Av. San Antonio MI 47096
>
> ---
>
> CompanyX
>   **Customer Service** 48 Dolor. Av. Muskegon KY 12482

My vcard html goes like this:

```
<div class="vcard">
<strong class="org">CompanyX <span class="category">Office</span></strong>
<div class="adr">
    <div class="street-address">28 Nulla St.</div>
    <span class="postal-code">96522</span> <span class="locality">Mankato Mississippi</span>
</div>
```

Comment: OK. So what's the question?

Comment: yes.. the question ;) I not sure if 'category' class is best way for address type.. maybe you know better solutions for address type in hcard html format